# Pandas Dataframe possibly uses wrong column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use python scripts to get data from a huge database. Right now I'm interested in extracting data by shopping baskets using transaction ID, but I got really weird results like mean shopping bag size of  9000 elements and strong alcohol on every shopping basket in a shop.

I had an Idea that maybe pandas uses the wrong column for some reason while reading in the data, because the basket sizes would make sense if it sorted them by user_id not transaction_id.

Is this possible? Can something go wrong while reading the csv?

This is the part of code that deals with sorting by transaction_id. It works just fine on a smaller dataset, but gets crazy on the huge data. But maybe I have a stupid mistake I'm unable to see and I'd be really thankful for someone to point out.

```
dt = pd.read_csv("../data/DataMining_with_cl_nr.txt", sep=";", engine='python',usecols=['TSEKK_ID', 'BARCODE','D_INVENTSITE_ID'], chunksize=100000)
df = pd.concat(dt)

def rec_dd():

    return defaultdict(rec_dd)

lengths = []
shopdic = rec_dd()
for i in range(1,48):
    subset = df.loc[df['D_INVENTSITE_ID'] == i]

    if not subset.empty:
        transactions = list(set(subset['TSEKK_ID']))
        baskets = []
        for n in range(len(transactions)):
            check = transactions[n]
            basket = list(subset.loc[subset['TSEKK_ID'] == check]['BARCODE'])
            baskets.append(basket)
        length = [len(x) for x in baskets]
        lengths.append(length)
        shopdic[i] = baskets
    else:
        shopdic[i] =  []
```

Comment: Are you sure that "strong alcohol on every shopping basket in a shop" is a detail relevant to your problem? We cannot judge, maybe that is perfectly normal behavior of your clients :-)

Comment: Honestly, you do not provide enough information. You really need to inspect `dt` (the result of `read_csv()`) for different pieces of test data. So **"Can something go wrong while reading the csv?"**. Sure, and you have to find out if this is the case!

Comment: I did not go through your code in all detail, because it smells. Almost never you need indices in Python, so `for i in range(1,48)` as well as the `for n in range(len(transactions))` make me believe that you first should write your logic with more idiomatic Python. Maybe then the issue is already gone.

Comment: Perhaps `basket = list(subset.loc[subset['TSEKK_ID'] == check]['BARCODE'])` should be `basket = list(subset.loc[subset['TSEKK_ID'].isin(check)]['BARCODE'])`? It is very difficult for others to check your code without sample data.